# visual c++ parallel port control

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, port

I wrote this code in Visual c++ to control LED's through parallel port:

// InpoutTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "stdio.h"
 #include "string.h"
 #include "stdlib.h"
 #include <conio.h>

 short _stdcall Inp32(short PortAddress);
 void _stdcall Out32(short PortAddress, short data);


 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
     Out32(888, 255);
     system("pause");
         Out32(888, 0);

     return 0;
 }
```

Now, what I thought was that the line 'Out32(888, 255);' will write 1 in all data registers, and all LED'd connected from D0 to D7 will turn on; but nothing happened, the led's which were on before execution remained on and same case with the led's which were off.

Same was the case with 'Out32(888, 0);', no led's were turned off.

What is wrong in the above code? I used 'Inpoutx64.dll' as I'm working on 64 bit OS (windows 8). I also included 'Inpoutx64.lib' in project properties > linked > input > Additional dependencies.

I've also copied "inpoutx64.dll' to Windows/system 32

Comment: Are you compiling this to run in protected mode?  Or real mode?  That is, will you run it under windows?

Comment: Yes, I will run it under windows, to be more specific under Windows 7 of Windows 8 (32/644 bit)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `inpoutx64.dll` in the same directory as your generated `.exe` file, and that you have run the `InstallDriver.exe` program included with `inpoutx64.dll`, and allowed UAC elevation, in order to install the required system driver.

Comment: InstallDriver.exe did not came with the download of 'inpoutx64.dll'. Where can I get it and what is it's purpose?

Comment: Should be available from [here](http://www.highrez.co.uk/Downloads/InpOut32/default.htm) - although I have not personally used the 64-bit version of this (only the 32-bit version)

Comment: Which version should I use, the 32 bit or 64 bit version? My OS is 64 bit but the c++ console application I'm building is 32 bit>

Comment: If your OS is x64 I believe the 64-bit .dll/driver is the way to go.